# Alternative words of "predation" for plant-eating animals?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am looking for a word meaning the action of ingesting food by plant-eating animals.

I think *predation* is only for carnivores.

Are there some alternative words of predation for plant-eating animals?

Comment: What do you think 'predation' means, and why do you think it can only be used for carnivores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For herbivores, I would prefer using [foraging](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forage)

> food for animals especially when taken by browsing or grazing.

Predation would typically be used when the food source is sentient, and capable of escaping. When the food source is immobile, the term foraging sounds much better.